# Ignore case of xpath extracted value in Mule expression

Tags: mule, expression, mule-el, mule-esb

The Mule expression that I have is:

```
xpath3('//CallingSourceSystemNm') == "CIMLOOKUP"
```

and I want to pass this condition even when there is value like

```
"CIMLOOKUP" that is upper
"CIMLOOKup" that is mixed
"cimlookup" that is lower
```

I tried the mule documentation and blogs before asking this question here. Let me know here if anybody has any clue about this.

Answer (score 0):

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.upperCase(xpath3('//CallingSourceSystemNm')) =="CIMLOOKUP"
```

I figured this out this way.

Thanks
Dhanjeet